# When can cash flow per share be more than earning per share?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-analysis

I saw a few cases for stocks where the cash flow per share was more than earning per share of the stock. But couldn't understand the reason behind it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confusion between revenue, earnings, investment and cash flow](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/96229/confusion-between-revenue-earnings-investment-and-cash-flow)

Answer (score 1):

There could be several reasons, and it depends on whether you're looking at *total* cash flow or *operating* cash flow. Two very common reasons for cash flow being larger than earnings are:

- If a company sells stock or borrows money, that is positive cash flow but is not income
- If a company has large expenses that do not mean cash out of the company (like depreciation) that is a reduction of earnings but not cash flow

Answer (score 0):

Cash flow is not the same as earnings, based on accounting rules that attempt to provide a more accurate and stable picture of a company's operations. What makes them different?

(A) Sometimes cash purchases are not considered expenses [like if a company buys a building, that isn't an 'expense' on the income statement, instead it is an increase to assets on the balance sheet], so cashflow is often less than earnings.

(B) Some times expenses are not cash-based. A common examples would be depreciation of fixed assets [like buildings, which weren't expensed originally, but are taken as expenses over time {to reflect that the building wears down over time}].

If A < B, then cashflow will be higher than earnings.

Comment: I didn't understand this well.

Comment: @Suchi Are you trying to use an understanding of these terms to decide how to invest? If you are, I think you might be well in over your head; be very careful not to invest in something you don't understand.

Comment: No, I just wanted to understand when that happens, for my knowledge

Comment: Earnings of a company and cashflow of a company are different thing. So earnings / shares is different than cashflow / shares.

Comment: so earnings is basically related to market sentiments, and cash flow per share is the money behind one share that the company is earning

Comment: Now i have one more doubt, for one company I saw, free cash flow per share was more than cash flow per share. Now as far as I know, free cash is the money that the company is left with after all expenses are done. Then how come, free cash flow> cash flow per share?

Comment: Really sorry for these questions, but I am new to all of it. Also, in annual report of company what I should focus on? it is 300 pages long for most of the companies!

Comment: The questions you are asking are very low-level. I mean no offense, we all start somewhere - but this isn't really a good way to learn such a broad subject. This isn't really on-topic for the site; there is just too much to go through in a single answer.

Comment: can you please explain, if possible?

Comment: No, the amount of time it would take to explain based on your current understanding, is just far too much. You are asking for many books' worth of information.

Answer (score 0):

Think of your own personal cash flow. You have assets other than cash, so your change in wealth (net income/earnings) is not just "cash in minus cash out".

When you buy a car, a house, or a stock, you lose cash but gain another asset, so you haven't suddenly lost the amount you paid. When those assets change in value, your wealth changes without a corresponding cash flow.

When you pay off debt, you eliminate a liability, so again the cash you paid isn't simply lost.

Your cash flows that *do* directly affect your wealth are things like salary, rent, and food, which are paid to/by you in maintaining your daily life, and don't correspond to offsetting assets.

Companies are similar.